# Could not connect to postgres after installing 9.4 and uninstalling 9.3

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

I have installed postgresql 9.4 and I removed postgresql 9.3 from my computer. Now when I try to run:

```
foo@bar:~$ psql
```

I get the error

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Note:

```
foo@bar:~$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.4.2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolve the problem changin the port from 5433 to 5432